# Averaging two columns with partial matching in R (big size data)

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a matrix which has 562709 rows and 803 columns, and for the columns, it has 7 metadata and 796 replicates data which should be combined in pair and take the average.

I googled the same problems but it didn't work well especially since my matrix is so huge, so I wonder if anybody can help me with this matter.

```
 [1] "seqnames"                                                          
 [2] "start"                                                             
 [3] "end"                                                               
 [4] "name"                                                              
 [5] "score"                                                             
 [6] "annotation"                                                        
 [7] "GC"                                                                
 [8] "ACCx_025FE5F8_885E_433D_9018_7AE322A92285_X034_S09_L133_B1_T1_PMRG"
 [9] "ACCx_025FE5F8_885E_433D_9018_7AE322A92285_X034_S09_L134_B1_T2_PMRG"
[10] "ACCx_2A5AE757_20D5_49B6_95FF_CAE08E8197A0_X012_S05_L033_B1_T1_P024"
[11] "ACCx_2A5AE757_20D5_49B6_95FF_CAE08E8197A0_X012_S05_L034_B1_T2_P025"
[12] "ACCx_3D0CD3BD_3960_46FB_92C3_777F11CCD0FC_X011_S06_L011_B1_T1_P024"
[13] "ACCx_3D0CD3BD_3960_46FB_92C3_777F11CCD0FC_X011_S06_L012_B1_T2_P026"
[14] "ACCx_4D0D43F5_D8F0_4735_92D5_F40E321C7A05_X010_S09_L065_B1_T1_P019"
[15] "ACCx_4D0D43F5_D8F0_4735_92D5_F40E321C7A05_X010_S09_L066_B1_T2_P020"
[16] "ACCx_81A262BD_3078_4BDB_8EB1_30DD6D7948C3_X027_S03_L081_B1_T1_P063"
[17] "ACCx_81A262BD_3078_4BDB_8EB1_30DD6D7948C3_X027_S03_L082_B1_T2_P067"
...
[800]"UCEC_C335297F_2D63_4973_9182_FA18C28E001E_X037_S04_L055_B1_T1_P088"
[801]"UCEC_C335297F_2D63_4973_9182_FA18C28E001E_X037_S04_L056_B1_T2_P089"
[802]"UCEC_D820B024_6B3B_4B5B_866E_F9A8139C270B_X039_S09_L113_B1_T1_P099"
[803]"UCEC_D820B024_6B3B_4B5B_866E_F9A8139C270B_X039_S09_L114_B1_T2_P098"
```

Like above, the first 7 columns shouldn't be modified, but for the columns from 8, pair should be combined as their average. (eg. column 8,9 should be combined, and 10,11...)

Comment: will each row you want to combine have the same ID? if so you can use `ddply(data, .(id_col_name), summarise, mean(cols_to_avg, na.rm=T))`

Comment: Yes they have the same ID, but the problem is that I need to consider the partial matching for example to the 50th char of the string(e.g. only part of a string. "ACCx_025FE5F8_885E_433D_9018_7AE322A92285_X034_S09" out of " ACCx_025FE5F8_885E_433D_9018_7AE322A92285_X034_S09_L133_B1_T1_PMRG") How can I solve this problem? And thank you for the answer

Comment: `I <- seq(8, 803, by=2);
sapply(I, function(i) rowMeans(dat[, i:(i+1)]))`

Comment: make a new ID column that substrings the current ID column so they will match

Comment: @jogo This is simple but it perfectly worked and helped me so much. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get alternating columns, add them, and divide by 2:

```
# example data, 5 rows, 11 cols
x <- mtcars[1:5,  ]

cbind(
  # keep first 7 columns as is
  x[ 1:7 ],
  # then take alternating cols, add, and, divide by 2
  (x[ 8:11 ][, c(TRUE, FALSE) ] + x[ 8:11 ][, c(FALSE, TRUE) ]) / 2
  )
```

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) as well as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)?

Comment: No attempt, no MVCE

Comment: @Andreas by that rule, 90% of posts should be left to collect dust.

Comment: Answering poorly asked question only encourage such behavior, which does not follow the community guidelines